# Node.js - socket.io - refresh page and disconnect

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I use node.js and socket.io. When I refresh the page - the user connection is interrupted. How do I solve this problem?

I do not want, when the user to switch between pages disconnected.

Comment: Then use a single page application

Comment: @Raynos I need a multi-page application. Is there any solution?

Comment: persist the socket id in localStorage and reconnect when you change page

Comment: Try using hash links to not have users load another page and instead load content into the current page. https://github.com/flatiron/director

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I would go for the single page application approach myself.  But just fancying an alternative solution..

You could try using socket.io with an essentially hidden frame.  In one frame, you maintain your connection while the user is still able to navigate in the other.

You'll have to have some gluecode to pass messages between the frames, but that should be trivial I think.